# How to remove empty space in list and also adjust the updated list back to csv

Tags: pandas, for-loop, insert

I'm trying to use python to clean up data in csv file.

```
data = ['Code', 'Name',' Size ',' Sector',' Industry ']
```

Tried the following;

```
for x in data:
    print(data.strip())
```

it works where I can read the data in the format I want but the problem is it doesn't change the data in csv.

Comment: `data=[x.strip() for x in data]`......you are just printing `print(data.strip())` not assigning that back so that's why changes doesn't reflect back

Answer (score 1):

If you want to strip away space from string stored in a list you can do it with a list comprehension like this,

```
data = [item.strip() for item in data]
```

If you like to do this over a pandas dataframe column,

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

reassign the cleansed entries back to the data variable before saving it back to csv.

```
data = [x.strip() for x in data]
```

then save data to csv.